# how to dis play hyper links in description using content editor web part

Tags: sharepoint-designer

i have using content editor web part for displaying some details

but i have a problem am not getting hyperlinks in description am getting data like this

"If you're brand new to development at UC Berkeley, visit Are You New to Advancement? to get your bearings.Looking for training classes to take? Visit Advancement Training to find out which classes we recommend based on your job responsibilities."

but actually i want hyper links also like fallowing screen shot [image]

how can i get like this way any suggestions please that would be great helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

you can use Content link in your content. entering a hyperlink to a text file that contains HTML source code. The two valid hyperlink protocols that you can use are:
Hypertext Transfer Protocol (http://)
Hypertext Transfer Protocol with privacy, which uses Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption (https://)

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4988.sharepoint-2010-how-to-add-html-content-into-the-content-editor-webpart.aspx

Comment: i want to get dynamically not static uploading this links or data coming from list, am writing java script for this one